# Change date format inside datepicker of flutter_datetime_picker package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, datetimepicker

I want to change the date format to MM-DD-YYYY inside the datepicker, I'm using flutter_datetime_picker package. Default is showing like the image, Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Flutter provide default ShowDataPicker      

 void _presentDatePicker() {
      showDatePicker(
         context: context,
     initialDate: DateTime.now(),
       firstDate: DateTime(2019),
    lastDate: DateTime.now(),
       ).then((pickedDate) {
     if (pickedDate == null) {
       return;
      }
       setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
    });
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to do this in flutter_datetime_picker package

Comment: You can use this instead of flutter_datetime_picker package

Comment: yeah, I know, but the requirement is to do with this.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution for this?